Missing config file in nginx source?
I have already opened an issue on GitHub at the NGINX repository (https://github.com/nginx/nginx/issues/189) and would like to make sure again whether this is intended or not.
I want to compile nginx with openssl which I had to compile successfully myself. However, when I enter “make” for nginx, I always get this error:
cd /opt/nginx-1.26.2 \
&& if [ -f Makefile ]; then make clean; fi \
&& ./config --prefix=/opt/nginx-1.26.2/.openssl no-shared no-threads  \
&& make \
&& make install_sw LIBDIR=lib
make[2]: Entering directory '/opt/nginx-1.26.2'
rm -rf Makefile objs
make[2]: Leaving directory '/opt/nginx-1.26.2'
/bin/sh: line 3: ./config: No such file or directory
make[1]: *** [objs/Makefile:1641: /opt/nginx-1.26.2/.openssl/include/openssl/ssl.h] Error 127
make[1]: Leaving directory '/opt/nginx-1.26.2'
make: *** [Makefile:10: build] Error 2
bash-5.1# ./config
bash: ./config: No such file or directory

Configure Command:
./configure --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf --modules-path=/etc/nginx/modules/ --add-module=/opt/ModSecurity-nginx --with-http_ssl_module --with-http_auth_request_module --with-http_v2_module --with-http_v3_module  --with-http_realip_module --with-http_gunzip_module --with-openssl=/opt/nginx-1.26.2

Why are you running ./config when the binary in the dir is called configure?

./configure is usually run before building. Here ./config seems to be a part of build process (/bin/sh: line 3: ./config: No such file or directory in output). The manual run for ./config was just to check if it exists.

--with-openssl=/opt/nginx-1.26.2 is probably wrong.
nginx expects an openssl source tree for this option. While this could be located in /opt/nginx-1.26.2 it would be an odd name for openssl sources.
./config: No such file or directory refers to openssl's config script see e.g. https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/master/config
Since it's not present in your directory, it's likely not the openssl source dir.
Download openssl sources, unpack them somewhere, then point --with-openssl=/your/path/to/openssl/ and the openssl config script plus all other openssl sources should exist in that directory.
